# Adjusting the position of countour base plane in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, contour

I am trying to use `gnuplot` to plot the [graphene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphene) band structure as both surfaces and a countour plot at the base, set with `set contour base`, but I can't get rid of some axis lines and the plane where the contour is drawn is too far away from the surfaces when I place them in the adequate viewing angle.

Here is the code to plot the graph

```
# Setting ranges and function parameters
set xrange [-.55:.55]
set yrange [-1:1]

t=-3.033 s=0.129 a=1.43 * sqrt(3)

# Auxiliary functions
kx(x,y) = (2*pi/a) * (cos(pi/6)*x + sin(pi/6)*y) ky(x,y) = (2*pi/a) * (cos(pi/6)*x - sin(pi/6)*y)    
w(x,y) = sqrt(1+4*cos(0.5*sqrt(3)*kx(x,y)*a)*cos(0.5*a*ky(x,y)) + 4*(cos(0.5*ky(x,y)*a))**2)

#functions to be plotted
e(x,y) = (t*w(x,y))/(1+s*w(x,y))
e_estrela(x,y) = (-t*w(x,y))/(1-s*w(x,y))

# Setting up 3D plot appearance
set hidden3d
set contour base set cntrparam levels discrete 0,0.5,1,2,4,8
set view 75, 31, 0.601098, 1.4385
set isosamples 60

# Removing unwanted stuff
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset ztics
unset key 

splot e_estrela(x,y), e(x,y)
```

And the output I get (with the `pngcairo` terminal, but that's not relevant, I guess) is:
[image: Output from script above]

Is it possible to draw the contour base plane closer to the surfaces? And how about removing those vertical black lines?

For the first part, I tried playing wioth `set zrange` with no success. The base plane seems to be drawn a certain z-distance below the lowest z-range limit everytime.

Ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To adjust the distance between your data and the xy-plane use the option

```
set xyplane relative <value>
```

where `<value>` gives you the distance between the xy-plane and the minimal z-value in relative fraction of the hight of your plot. So `<value>=0` sets the distance to zero, `<value>=0.5` to half the hight.

To control the border use `set border` where each border line is represented by bits. Please refers to the [documentation](http://www.gnuplotting.org/manpage-gnuplot-4-6/#x1-199000III) for more details. In your case I would suggest:

```
set border 127+256+512 # or set border 1023-128
set grid #forces borders from xy-plane to plot
```

Comment: Thanks! The  `set xyplane` works exactly as I planned and I'm checking the docs to see which bits are responsible for each border segment.

Comment: I'm getting a werid behavior with the borders.
According to the documentation, `set border 15`, which means all bits from 1 to 8 ON and all others OFF, I get the borders on the xyplane, but also vertical lines connecting the corners of the abse plane to the highest of two functions. I have no idea how to get rid of them without post-processing. Ideas?

Comment: @EltonCarvalho That's indeed weird and there is no way to unset those vertical bars (only with `unset border`). As workaround, use `unset border; set style arrow 1 lt -1 nohead; set arrow from graph 0,0,0 to graph 1,0,0 as 1; set arrow from graph 1,0,0 to graph 1,1,0 as 1; set arrow from graph 1,1,0 to graph 0,1,0 as 1; set arrow from graph 0,1,0 to graph 0,0,0 as 1` (looks a bit ugly in the comment).

Comment: Alternative you could also split the contour plot and the surface plot into two separate plots, hiding the other respectively, and then use `multiplot` to overlap both (still a hack, but I would consider it cleaner, but not much).